# How to perform array operations in Google App Script?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I'm pretty new to AppScript and I have absolutely no idea how to manipulate arrays. I just want to be able to take one array and collapse the common elements in a separate array as follows;

```
groceryArray = [
                ["fruit", "apple"],
                ["fruit", "banana"], 
                ["veg", "potato"], 
                ["veg", "onion"], 
                ["veg", "broccoli"],
               ]
```

and turn that into this...

```
groceryArray2 = [
                  ["fruit", ["apple", "banana"]], 
                  ["veg", ["potato", "onion", "broccoli"]],
                 ]
```

I would of thought it's fairly straightforward but I can't work it out at all...

Comment: How about doing converting it to `{"fruit",["apple","banana"],"veg":["potato","onion","brocolli"]}

Comment: Yeah, that could work. Is it easier to convert it into a dictionary?

Comment: @JonPhillips - it's not easier, it is more performant (albeit on such an array size it is pretty much irrelevant). Other than that, not much of a difference, it all depends on how you are going to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Create a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)  and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the array:

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/
const groceryArray = [
            ["fruit", "apple"],
            ["fruit", "banana"], 
            ["veg", "potato"], 
            ["veg", "onion"], 
            ["veg", "broccoli"],
           ],
  collapsedMap = groceryArray.reduce((m,[category,item]) => m.set(category, m.has(category) ? m.get(category).concat(item):[item]),new Map),
  collapsedArray = [...collapsedMap];
console.info({collapsedMap,collapsedArray});
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you actually want to achieve is fold a grid over the first column of each row. In a nutshell, this is a very simple algorithmic problem:

1. Iterate over grid rows, for each row check if the property exists and is an array:

   1. If yes, push the new item into the array.
   2. If no, set the property to be an array with one current item.

[TheMaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64378935/11407695) demonstrates one approach, below is an alternative one (they both follow the same algorithm) using [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), simple dictionary, and [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```js
const groceryArray = [
  ["fruit", "apple"],
  ["fruit", "banana"],
  ["veg", "potato"],
  ["veg", "onion"],
  ["veg", "broccoli"],
];

const fold = (grid, col = 0) => {

  const folded = {};

  for(const [ cat, item ] of grid) {
    const existing = folded[cat];
    
    if(existing) {
      existing.push(item);
      continue;
    }
    
    folded[cat] = [ item ];
  }
  
  return Object.entries(folded);
};

console.log( fold(groceryArray) );
```